# Is the set of all polynomial open in the space $C[-1, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of all polynomial open in the space $C[-1, 1]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Any open set that contains $0$ contains a ball around $0$. The polynomials are a subspace, so if they contain a ball around $0$ they have to be the whole space.

Answer (score 4):

No, in a ball around any polynomial you can find a continuous function that is not a polynomial. For instance by adding a suitably small bump function to it.